# Appending lists to new list in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

I am currently experimenting with lists in python and am trying to create a program that will simulate the name game [(click here for refrence)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Name_Game).

The program asks for user input and generates a list with each letter of the user's name. However, it then has to generate 3 new names, each beginning with "b", "f", "m". This is where I run into a problem. When appending to master_list, and later printing my result I get the output:

```
[['m', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], ['m', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], 
['m', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't']]
```

When user input = "Robert"

Heres my code:

```
# Asks for user name
user_name = input("Enter name here: ")
name = list(user_name)

# Create an empty list that will contain a subsets of lists.
master_list = []

# List containing the first letter of each new name
beginning_of_word = ["b", "f", "m"]

# Creates 3 new names and appends them to master_list
for var in beginning_of_word:
    new_list = name
    new_list.pop(0)
    new_list.insert(0, var)
    print(new_list)
    master_list.append(new_list)
    if new_list != name:
        new_list = name
```

The intended output when master_list is printed should be:

```
[['b', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], ['f', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], 
['m', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't']]
```

Does anyone have ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Although you named your variable `new_list`, the fact is you were operating on the same *old* list each time.  To modify a list, and retain the original, you need to *copy* the list:

```
# Asks for user name
user_name = input("Enter name here: ")
name = list(user_name)

# Create an empty list that will contain a subsets of lists.
master_list = []

# List containing the first letter of each new name
beginning_of_word = ["b", "f", "m"]

# Creates 3 new names and appends them to master_list
for var in beginning_of_word:
    new_list = list(name)  # a copy of 'name'
    new_list[0] = var
    master_list.append(new_list)

print(master_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
Enter name here: Robert
[['b', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], ['f', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], ['m', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't']]
%
```

Comment: Thanks. I came across this when testing with my code just now. Creating a new list solved it.